# HTTPS Contract Mismatch issue WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, security, iis, wcf-security

I have installed self https certificate in my IIS and changed my EchoService from http to https in my local machine.

But I am getting below error after choosing transport sercurity.

The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

**Client App Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EchoService">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://desktop-rfd4j23/WCFASPNETSecurityEx/EchoService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="EchoService" contract="EchoService.IEchoService" name="EchoService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Service Web Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFASPNETSecurityEx.EchoServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFASPNETSecurityEx.EchoServiceBehavior" name="WCFASPNETSecurityEx.EchoService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" 
                  name="EchoService" contract="WCFASPNETSecurityEx.IEchoService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Client Code:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter when the web server is started");
Console.ReadLine();

EchoServiceClient client = new EchoServiceClient();
String result = client.Echo("Hello WCF");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I am getting error while invoking client.Echo("Hello WCF"); Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing using https and the cert was not issued to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I should have mentioned wsHttpBinding instead of webHttpBinding.

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp" hostNameComparisonMode="Exact">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"></message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are locking down your transport with https and requiring UserName authentication. 
Shouldn't the Security Mode be set to :

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
```

Are you handling that in your client anywhere?

```
<serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="xxx.MyUserNameValidator,xxx.WCF.Security"/>
</serviceCredentials>
```